# Mapbox gl : On mouse hover on layers change cursor pointer style

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have 10 to 15 different different layers for example car,bus,route etc etc.These layer i am adding dynamic on map when if needed because all the time all layers are does not exist on map.

So i am showing info on single click about layers,but i want when i hover mouse on layer change mouse pointer cursor style to 'crosshair'.

i have written change cursor style on mouseenter event but it seems sometimes working and sometime even though mouse is on hover on layer but cursor style does not get changed.

**First way:**

```
 map.on('mouseenter', (e: any) => {
      self.mapInstance.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'crosshair';
    });
```

**Second Way:**

```
      map.on('mouseenter',(e: any) => {         
       var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point,{ layers: ['Car',"Bus"] });
//error let's say any layer still on exist on map
        if(features.length)
         map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'crosshair';    
            });
```

**My issues**:

1. Cursor style not getting change
2. Error on queryRenderedFeatures like layer does not exists
3. Mouse flickering on hover layer

How to get change style of the cursor on mouse hover on different different layers?

Comment: What is in the layer? `mouseenter` will run on your mouse hovering over a feature, not anywhere in the layer

Answer (score 19):

```
map.on('mouseenter', 'clusters', () => {
  map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer'
})
map.on('mouseleave', 'clusters', () => {
  map.getCanvas().style.cursor = ''
})
```

This is how to get it working with clusers specifically but the code might still be helpful.

Good luck !

Comment: Use mouseover instead of mouseenter

Comment: `mouseenter` event is never called for me, but `mouseover` is. Thanks @hjahan

Answer (score 6):

```
 map.on("mouseenter", layer.id, () => {
          map.getCanvas().style.cursor = "pointer";
        });

 map.on("mouseleave", shape.id, () => {
          map.getCanvas().style.cursor = "default";
        });
```

You can add custom events to each layer, such as clicks. Same goes for mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

How about on mousemove?

// some padding since SO needs 30 chars minimum to post...

Comment: No,not wokering with mousemove event also....and getting this error on console when map loading first time.
Error: The layer 'Car' does not exist in the map's style and cannot be queried for features.
    at i.queryRenderedFeatures (mapbox-gl.js:33)

Comment: Maybe put your on mousemove inside on load